# The smallest ideal containing $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

In a commutative ring $R$, the ideal generated by the set $S=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$, where $S$ is a subset of $R$. 
$$(a_1,\dots,a_n):= \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n r_ka_k: r_k\in R\right\}$$

is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing $S$.

How can I prove it ?

Comment: This is a question designed to test your comprehension of the definitions at play. If you write down the necessary requirement that an ideal be closed under addition (within the ideal) and multiplication (by elements in the ring), then you'll get sums of the form you describe. Then it is quick to see that these form an ideal.

Comment: Just a small remark.  The OP's statement is only true if $R$ is unital (which most people assume).  If $R$ is non-unital, then the ideal generated by $S$ is $$\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n\,\left(m_k\,a_k+r_k\,a_k\right)\,\Big|\,m_k\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ and }r_k\in R\text{ for all}k=1,2,\ldots,n\right\}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

As @mixedmath stated above, showing $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is an ideal is a quick exercise and tests your understanding of the various definitions.

To show $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing $S = \{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$, you want to show that if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ that contains $S$, then $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \subseteq I$; this is also straightforward.